# How to give delay between each requests in scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I don't want to crawl simultaneously and get blocked. I would like to send one request per second.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30404364/scrapy-delay-request) you have an explicit solution.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

There is a [setting](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay) for that:

> `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`
>
> Default: `0`
>
> The amount of time (in secs) that the downloader should wait before
>   downloading consecutive pages from the same website. This can be used
>   to throttle the crawling speed to avoid hitting servers too hard.

```
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.25    # 250 ms of delay
```

Read the docs: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: If you put `DOWNLOAD_DELAY=1`, I don't think you can get 60 pages in one minute. It is also restrained by the downloading speed and all kinds of overhead. I would say it only give you a scraping upper limit so you don't hit target sites too much.

Answer (score 20):

You can also set 'download_delay' attribute on spider if you don't want a global download delay. See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#what-does-the-response-status-code-999-means

Comment: Download delay per spider see also https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html

Answer (score 11):

```py
class S(Spider):
    rate = 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.download_delay = 1/float(self.rate)
```

*rate* sets a maximum amount of pages could be downloaded in one second.

Comment: Can you please add a description or some explaination of what this does. As it stands I have to vote this answer for deletion.

Comment: @AndréYuhai, I can't find official doc for that but in the source.  In `_get_concurrency_delay` function from `scrapy/core/downloader/__init__.py`.

Answer (score 10):

Beside DOWNLOAD_DELAY, you can also use AUTOTHROTTLE feature of scrapy, 
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html

It changes delay amount between requests depending on settings file. If you set 1 for both start and max delay, it will wait 1 second in each request.

It's original purpose is to vary delay time so detection of your bot will be harder.

You just need to set it in settings.py as follows:

```
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 1
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 3
```

Comment: didn't even know about this until now. can those go in the `custom_settings` dict? thanks!

Comment: I believe that will work as well. As custom_settings can overwrite general settings per spider.

Answer (score 7):

Delays Can we set in 2 says:-

We can specify the delay while running the crawler.
Eg. scrapy crawl sample --set DOWNLOAD_DELAY=3 ( which means 3 seconds delay between two requests)

Or else we can specify Globaly in the settings.py 
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3

by default scrapy takes 0.25 seconds delay between 2 requests.

Answer (score 6):

if you want to keep a download delay of exactly one second, setting `DOWNLOAD_DELAY=1` is the way to do it.

But scrapy also has a feature to automatically set download delays called `AutoThrottle`. It automatically sets delays based on load of both the Scrapy server and the website you are crawling. This works better than setting an arbitrary delay.

Read further about this on http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/autothrottle.html#autothrottle-extension
I've crawled more than 100 domains and not been blocked with AutoThrottle turned on