# data used/transferred during web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

Is there any way to find out how much data is transferred from the web server to my machine during web scraping? I want to put minimal load on the web server. Also, I can try different techniques and use whichever put minimal load on the web server.

Comment: You can check the size of server response (for example, in `requests` library), but your 'load' is probably expressed in number of calls to the server per min or per hour too. It would have helped to know the motivation - low bandwidth for internet? Server behaviour on too many calls?

Comment: My internet speed is 100Mbps so no bandwidth issue. I am mainly concerned about server behavior.

Comment: Why not review some links on the subject, eg https://stackoverflow.com/q/8768439/1758363. Otherwise you question risks downvotes because of poor research effort.

Comment: As more general resourse: https://github.com/lorien/awesome-web-scraping/blob/master/python.md